# s3fs: Failed to access bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, fuse, s3fs

I have created a bucket, added a policy for full acess to a brand new IAM user and tried to mount the bucket as my archive folder on my server.
It just doesn't go. I am on a special cloud and the only downfall of my hosting company that the storage is small. S3 mounted archive storage sounds like the idea.

But when i tried and followed all available policies, s3fs fails to access bucket. I know it's me, i just don't know how.

```
[root@backoffice s3fs-1.74]# s3fs -f -d -d -o use_cache=/tmp mybucketname /opt/bigarchive
    set_moutpoint_attribute(3291): PROC(uid=0, gid=0) - MountPoint(uid=0, gid=0, mode=40777)
FUSE library version: 2.9.3
nullpath_ok: 0
nopath: 0
utime_omit_ok: 0
unique: 1, opcode: INIT (26), nodeid: 0, insize: 56, pid: 0
INIT: 7.13
flags=0x0000b07b
max_readahead=0x00020000
s3fs_init(2595): init
s3fs_check_service(2894): check services.
    CheckBucket(2228): check a bucket.
    RequestPerform(1467): connecting to URL http://mybucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/
RequestPerform(1595): ### CURLE_HTTP_RETURNED_ERROR
RequestPerform(1600): HTTP response code =403
s3fs: Failed to access bucket.
```

My Bucket policy is:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "mybucketnameS3PolicyId",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "IPAllow",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname /*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "MY.PUBLIC.IP.ADDRESS"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

My IAM policy is:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1423176468000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

S3fs is installed:

```
[root@backoffice s3fs-1.74]# s3fs --version
Amazon Simple Storage Service File System 1.74
Copyright (C) 2010 Randy Rizun 
License GPL2: GNU GPL version 2 
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Fuse as well:

```
[root@backoffice s3fs-1.74]# pkg-config --modversion fuse
2.9.3
```

Comment: Seems that there is something wrong with your security credentials set-up. I think s3fs does not specify a cache size limit. You would probably have to check and delete the cache manually or automatize it, for instance by using cron.

Comment: Yeah @phobic, that much i understand (the debug message of s3fs returns a 403 Forbidden). I am looking for some help where the problem might be.

Answer (score 0):

Your action should be

`"Action":   "s3:*"`

Also ensure that your IP address is the IP address that S3 would see (i.e. external IP address)

Comment: Nat, I edited my post so the '*' shows up correctly. That was not the issue, that's how the policy is. The IP address is public.

Comment: Have you tried to access the bucket using IAM policy from CloudBerry or other S3 client?

Comment: I did do a Policy Simulator test on Amazon for the IAM and it worked.